# Can I pipe vim spelling suggestions to an external program?

Tags: external-command, spell-checking

I know I can write a buffer to an external program with `:w !<command>`, but is there a way to pipe the contents of the spelling correction list I get with `z=` into  an external program (i.e. dmenu)? If the function(s) behind `z=` are written in vimscript, can I modify them or is it hard coded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `dmenu` installed, but I tried with `zenity`:

```
:echo system("zenity --list --column=Suggestions 2>/dev/null", spellsuggest(expand("<cword>")))
```

- `expand("<cword>")` expands to the word under the cursor.
- `spellsuggest(...)` returns a list of spelling suggestions
- `system("zenity...", ...)` calls `zenity` and pipes the the list from `spellsuggest(...)` as input.

If I then select one of the suggestions, it is echoed by Vim.

See the help for spellsuggest (`:h spellsuggest()`), as it can take additional parameters.

Comment: Using this I get a list but can this replace the word?

Comment: @Galilean Well, that was not the question :-). You would need additional scripting. Or maybe another question.

Answer (score 2):

My solution (as per the answer @Ralf gave) is this:

```
" Dmenu integration for searching spelling correction. Replaces `z=`.
function DmenuCorrect()
    let word=system("$HOME/.bin/dmenuw -i -l 8 2>/dev/null", spellsuggest(expand("<cword>")))
    if len(word) != 0 
        exe "normal ciw". word[0:-2]
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent>z= :call DmenuCorrect()<Cr>
```

Replacing the word under the cursor is done with `exe "normal ciw" . word [0:-2]`. `ciw` puts vim into replace mode within the current word boundaries. `word [0:-2]` is just to account for the newline dmenu prints, and inserts the chosen solution into the buffer in place of the now deleted misspelt word.